# How to check if x and y are in an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object containing some x and y positions:

```js
var positions = [
0: {x: 720, y: 389.5},
1: {x: 736, y: 373.5},
2: {x: 736, y: 357.5},
3: {x: 720, y: 373.5},
4: {x: 736, y: 389.5},
6: {x: 720, y: 373.5},
7: {x: 752, y: 389.5},
8: {x: 704, y: 357.5},
9: {x: 752, y: 341.5},
10: {x: 720, y: 405.5},
11: {x: 704, y: 373.5},
]
```

In a `setInterval` loop, I generate new coordinates and want to check if these coordinates exists in my object in order to regenerate them until getting unexisting coordinates. Let say:

```js
var newPosition = [720, 389.5];
// return true
var newPosition = [720, 357.5];
// return true
```

Comment: what is the wanted result? what happens with unknown coordinates? what about the last one, it isn't in the array.

Comment: Unknown coordinates are then pushed into the `positions` object. The purpose is to generate new coordinates at each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check the properties.

```js
const
    addTo = array => ([x, y]) => {
        if (positions.some(o => o.x === x && o.y === y)) return;
        array.push({ x, y });
    };

var positions = [{ x: 720, y: 389.5 }, { x: 736, y: 373.5 }, { x: 736, y: 357.5 }, { x: 720, y: 373.5 }, { x: 736, y: 389.5 }, { x: 720, y: 373.5 }, { x: 752, y: 389.5 }, { x: 704, y: 357.5 }, { x: 752, y: 341.5 }, { x: 720, y: 405.5 }, { x: 704, y: 373.5 }],
    add = addTo(positions);

add([720, 389.5]);
console.log(positions); // not added

add([720, 357.5]);
console.log(positions); // added
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be:

```js
var positions = [{ x: 720, y: 389.5 }, { x: 736, y: 373.5 }, { x: 736, y: 357.5 }, { x: 720, y: 373.5 }, { x: 736, y: 389.5 }, { x: 720, y: 373.5 }, { x: 752, y: 389.5 }, { x: 704, y: 357.5 }, { x: 752, y: 341.5 }, { x: 720, y: 405.5 }, { x: 704, y: 373.5 }];


const adder = ([x, y]) => {
    if (!positions.find(obj => obj.x === x && obj.y === y)) {
        positions.push({x, y});
    }
};

adder([10, 20]); // was added
console.log(positions);
adder([720, 389.5]); // wasn't added
console.log(positions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```